# .htaccess rewrite incomplete

Tags: redirect, httpd

How can I rewrite
`www.mysite.com/name/subject/`
to
`www.mysite.com/index.php?page=name&s=subject`?

Now I'm using:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

Don't match internal sub requests:
`RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$`

Match the query string variable:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?page=(name1|name2)(&.*)?$ [NC]`

Match the file and redirect:
`RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /%2/? [NC,R=301,L]`
`RewriteRule ^(name1|name2)\/$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]`

And it's working but only until `www.mysite.com/name1/`

Answer (score 1):

[**RewriteConds apply to the next following RewriteRule.**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Also, don't use .htaccess unless you have no alternative; whenever you have access to httpd.conf, you should put your rewrites there instead.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I don't have access to httpd.conf because my access on server is limited to a simple cpanel.